# Returning audio using os.system Python FIXED

Tags: python, audio, pyttsx

I would like to return audio using os.system because, in PyCharm, it returns the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Milo/Desktop/python/Joe.py", line 5, in 
>       import pyttsx
>     File "/private/var/folders/z_/wpk6crsn2slfh_1y5hytwsvr0000gp/T/Joe.py/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx/**init**.py", line 18, in 
>       from engine import Engine
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'".

For example:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('This is a test')
engine.runAndWait()
'''Somehow play sound/voice'''
```

Am I using the wrong pyttsx module? Did I install it wrong? I am using python 3.6.4 and am using Mac OSX. I highly prefer that if I need a new module, it works with NSSpeechSynthesizer. Should I just run it via terminal? However, I would like to use it with PyCharm. Let me know if there if there is any info you need to know the I did not disclose.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Is OS X you can use the say command in the terminal

`say "hello"`

Comment: Is the module available in the interpreter assigned to the project in PyCharm?

Comment: "Is OS X you can use the say command in the terminal say "hello" – Chris" This worked! Thanks! Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While Mac OSX has the say command to speak, or so to say, is there any command that is similar for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387676/while-mac-osx-has-the-say-command-to-speak-or-so-to-say-is-there-any-command-t)